# Book: Continuous martingale and Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

I am reading the book "continuous martingale and Brownian motion" [1995_Revuz](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-06400-9). It reads the following proposition 3.2 in Chapter VII. That confused me a lot. Where $T_r, T_l$ is the hitting time for $r,l$. My question is that: by the proof of Proposition 3.2 and proposition 3.2 we get $s(x)=P_x(T_r<T_l)=\frac{s(x)-s(l)}{s(r)-s(l)}$. Forgot the middle term,  we get $s(x)=\frac{s(x)-s(l)}{s(r)-s(l)}$. It seems impossible. Where I am understanding wrong?

[image: position 3.2][image: proof of proposition 3.2]

Comment: $s(l)=0$ and $s(r)=1$. So, $s(x)=\frac{s(x)-s(l)}{s(r)-s(l)}$.

Comment: no, it is possible that $s(l+)$  goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: The limit $s(l+)$ is a limit and hence cannot go anywhere -- least of all to $-\infty$, since $s(x)$ is a probability.